# In Guild Wars 2, what I should do with unwanted equipments?

Tags: guild-wars-2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Most profitable way to get rid of equipment](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/81929/most-profitable-way-to-get-rid-of-equipment)

So, in Guild Wars 2 you have four things you can do with unwanted equipments:

- Sell on a vendor.
- Salvage the equipment.
- Mystic Forge.
- If you're lucky and the item is worth something, sell on the Trading Post.

Usually I salvage Basic (white) items and Mystic Forge the rest to try to get better equips, but this probably is nonsense.

What is the best strategy?